# How to make predictions in Keras using Tensorflow's Dataset API

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I was trying to build model in Keras using Tensorflow's Dataset API. I successfully able to train model in keras. But for making a prediction for test data. it need to be in numpy array.

https://keras.io/models/model/

x needs to be numpy array. So i done something like this

```
x = input_fn('test.tfrecords')
model = models.load_model("model/model-40-0.35.hdf5")

with tf.Session()) as sess:  
          x_out = np.asarray(sess.run(x))
pred = model.predict(x_out,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=1)
print(pred)
```

it successfully made predictions, but i was thinking if there is any method where i able to insert tensor to a function for predictions. And not first converting it to numpy array.

I found this https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model#predict

But even whenever I input the tensor , this error comes

> TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Comment: `predict` works with `tf.data`. Could you show the definition of `input_fn`?

Comment: input_fn is just one shot iterator.

Comment: Could you post the code you used which raised that `TypeError`?

Answer (score 0):

The very first parameter of the `predict` method (method of tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model instance) can be either of:

- A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays  (in case the model has multiple inputs).
- A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).
- A `tf.data` dataset or a dataset iterator.
- A generator or `keras.utils.Sequence` instance.

So it can be a tensor. In your case `x_out` argument can take a tensor.